# Cordova + MapboxGL + Ios loading Images -Images not loading

Tags: ios, cordova, mapbox-gl-js

We are implementing a small Cordova-App using MapBoxGL. We are loading PNG-Markers to mark certain Objects in the index.js like

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    $.support.cors = true;
    map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        center: [8.984397559637734, 48.70103302426699],  
        zoom: 14,  
        minZoom: 14,
        maxZoom: 22,  
        style:  MAPSTYLE
    });


    map.on('load', function() {
            map.loadImage('./img/car16.png', (error, image) => {
                if (error) {
                    alert("Car16 image not loaded");
                    console.error(error);
                    throw error;
                }
                map.addImage('car16', image);
            }); ....
```

This works fine using **cordova run browser** and using an **Android-Device** , but fails to load, when the Cordova-App is being deployd to an iOS Device.

Any Ideas about that ?

Comment: How you bind mapbox-gl-js? By http or local?

Comment: Tested both . .. http and local 
<script src='js/mapbox-gl.js'></script> and   <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.35.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>

Comment: I was having similar problem with font awesome if i remember correctly you need to add css and fonts as resources to the IOS project

Comment: Hmm well the Images are in the Project itself .. do I have to mark the Files or the Folder  somehow as Resource ?

Comment: Look here may be this will help you https://github.com/trevorpowell/mapbox-gl-js-cordova-offline-example/issues/2 . Can't find link for adding resources

Comment: Wel it seems that it works, if I am using a remote Image like https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/60/Cat_silhouette.svg/400px-Cat_silhouette.svg.png ... but "..foo.png" or "file://foo.png" does not work ..

Comment: Still this only seems to be a ONLY ios-Problem =(